# Transformar NULL em NA

Tags: r, null

Eu tenho uma base de dados com 30 colunas e 500 linhas. Ao juntar as os dados que resultaram nesta, os valores vazios foram colocados como NULL. Para conseguir salvar, eu preciso colocar como NA. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Quando tento salvar, o erro que aparece é esse:

```
Error in write.table(comissoes.wide.3, "membroscomissoes.csv", fileEncoding = "Latin1") : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Tentei assim, mas não funcionou:

```
df[is_empty(df)] = NA
```

Não altera a base de dados, nem cria um objeto.
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.

```
dput(head(comissoes.wide.3, 20))
structure(list(id = c("204507", "135054", "204560", "141372", 
"218879", "204400", "74383", "204386", "204538", "74399", "160673", 
"178901", "74141", "204574", "74052", "136811", "141411", "160632", 
"160559", "162332"), nome = c("Carla Zambelli", "Cristiano Vale", 
"Adolfo Viana", "Aelton Freitas", "Nelho Bezerra", "Aline Sleutjes", 
"Giacobo", "Jose Mario Schreiner", "Paulo Bengtson", "Onyx Lorenzoni", 
"Giovani Cherini", "Tereza Cristina", "Josias Gomes", "Junior Lourenço", 
"Bosco Costa", "Afonso Hamm", "Dagoberto Nogueira", "Zé Silva", 
"Alceu Moreira", "Luiz Nishimori"), siglaPartido = c("PL", "PP", 
"PSDB", "PP", "UNIÃO", "PROS", "PL", "MDB", "PTB", "PL", "PL", 
"PP", "PT", "PL", "PL", "PP", "PSDB", "SOLIDARI", "MDB", "PSD"
), siglaUf = c("SP", "PA", "BA", "MG", "CE", "PR", "PR", "GO", 
"PA", "RS", "RS", "MS", "BA", "MA", "SE", "RS", "MS", "MG", "RS", 
"PR"), CAPADR = list("Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", 
    "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", 
    "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", 
    "Titular", "Titular", "Titular", "Titular"), CCTCI = list(
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", 
    NULL), CCJC = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CDC = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CDU = list("Suplente", 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CDHM = list(
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), 
    CDEICS = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL), CE = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CFT = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", 
        "Suplente", NULL, NULL), CFFC = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CME = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL), CSSF = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CTASP = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL), CVT = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", 
        NULL, NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), 
    CINDRA = list(NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CREDN = list(NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Titular", NULL, 
        NULL, "Suplente", "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, "Suplente"), CLP = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Titular", NULL, NULL), 
    CSPCCO = list(NULL, NULL, "Titular", NULL, "Suplente", NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CTUR = list(NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, "Titular", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL), CMADS = list("Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, "Titular", "Titular", NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Titular", NULL, NULL), 
    CCULT = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL), CPD = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        "Suplente", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), CMULHER = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL), CIDOSO = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "Titular", 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), mesa.diretora = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    participacao_comissoes = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(comissoes.wide.3)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(comissoes.wide.3, 20))`? É difícil responder sem ver os dados, sobretudo quando o problema é precisamente aí que está.

Comment: Coloquei o dput(head(comisssoes.wide.3,20)). Estou aprendendo as melhores formas de colocar minhas dúvidas no fórum ainda, desculpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As colunas com `NULL` são todas de classe `"list"`, portanto primeiro cria-se um índice que identifique essas colunas. Depois aplica-se só a essas colunas a transformação de `NULL` em `NA`.

```r
i_list <- which(sapply(comissoes.wide.3, is.list))
comissoes.wide.3[i_list] <- lapply(comissoes.wide.3[i_list], \(x){
  x <- sapply(x, \(y){
    is.na(y) <- is.null(y)
    y
  })
  x
})
str(comissoes.wide.3)
#> tibble [20 × 30] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ id                    : chr [1:20] "204507" "135054" "204560" "141372" ...
#>  $ nome                  : chr [1:20] "Carla Zambelli" "Cristiano Vale" "Adolfo Viana" "Aelton Freitas" ...
#>  $ siglaPartido          : chr [1:20] "PL" "PP" "PSDB" "PP" ...
#>  $ siglaUf               : chr [1:20] "SP" "PA" "BA" "MG" ...
#>  $ CAPADR                : chr [1:20] "Titular" "Titular" "Titular" "Titular" ...
#>  $ CCTCI                 : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CCJC                  : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CDC                   : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CDU                   : chr [1:20] "Suplente" NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CDHM                  : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CDEICS                : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CE                    : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CFT                   : chr [1:20] NA NA NA "Suplente" ...
#>  $ CFFC                  : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CME                   : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CSSF                  : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CTASP                 : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CVT                   : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CINDRA                : chr [1:20] NA "Suplente" NA NA ...
#>  $ CREDN                 : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CLP                   : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CSPCCO                : chr [1:20] NA NA "Titular" NA ...
#>  $ CTUR                  : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CMADS                 : chr [1:20] "Suplente" NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CCULT                 : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CPD                   : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CMULHER               : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ CIDOSO                : chr [1:20] NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ mesa.diretora         : num [1:20] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ participacao_comissoes: num [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 2 2 NA ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo!!! funciou!